# c# VSTO Host WPF form inside Excel sheet

Tags: c#, wpf, excel, vsto

I would like to embed a standalone WPF form inside an Excel sheet.

Microsoft provide information on how to host a WPF form inside an Excel Action Pane or Task Pane here: https://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/bb772076.aspx

However, I'm unable to find information on how I can do this within the Excel sheet itself. Is this possible? Should I just load the form when the user clicks on the tab? Or is there a better way to do this?

Answer (score 0):

I've never seen that anywhere so I guess it's not possible.
What I have done a few times (*but never in production*) is your second suggestion

> Should I just load the form when the user clicks on the tab? Or is there a better way to do this?

Yes, this should work fine, there is something like WPF host you can use on standard form or create another project  in your solution (*WPF project*) and call it from VSTO

Comment: You can just open WPF windows in a VSTO project. There is nothing stopping you from doing it; you don't need to use an ElementHost or anything special. It works fine except sometimes it won't open in the foreground, and the positioning can be a little annoying. There are ways to fix the former, maybe even the latter.